# Print only once after max is reached

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to execute the final `print` statement only once, after `max_rows` is reached.

Let's say you need to fill a list with 30 elements, but only want to print the first 20 times, then simply want to keep appending to the list without printing anything, except "Truncating..." (once).

This is an ugly way to accomplish this. What could be a more elegant approach?

```
max_rows = 20
max_rows_exceeded = False
rows = 0
i = 0
my_list = list()
while i < 30:
    i += 1
    if rows < max_rows:
        print("rows < max_rows  -   %s" % rows)
        rows += 1
    else:
        max_rows_exceeded = True
    my_list.append(i)
if max_rows_exceeded:
    print("Truncating due to max displayable row number exceeded: %s" % max_rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to check if the rows exceeded ***inside*** the loop. You can check this *"mathematically"* after the loop:

```py
max_rows = 20
my_list = []

upper_limit = 30
for rows in range(upper_limit):
    if rows < max_rows:
        print("rows < max_rows  -   %s" % rows)
    my_list.append(rows)

if max_rows < upper_limit:
    print("Truncating due to max displayable row number exceeded: %s" % max_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. This one seems a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
max_rows = 20
rows = 0
while rows < max_rows:
    print("rows < max_rows  -   %s" % rows)
    rows += 1
print("Truncating due to max displayable row number exceeded: %s" % max_rows)
```

Comment: You're always printing the `Truncating...` message but don't know if it's actually truncated this way...

Comment: Sorry I edited the code. There is other code to be executed in the loop, so it must keep iterating.